# JPA Relationship between OO Model and Relational Model

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Working on a relationship between a User Object and Preferences Object. Each user should have one preference object associated with it. i.e. one to one relationship between user and preference. I would also like to enforce that User cannot have a null Preference.

My Classes structure.

```
public class User{
...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
    public Preference preference;
...
}
public class Preference{
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    public User user;
    ...
 }
```

When JPA generates the tables, the foreign-key column is in the Preference table. Reading around the web, this is preferred vs having the foreign-key in the User table.

**Note: I have made this a bidirectional relationship.**

Although this generated proper tables, I would like to enforce in db layer that User should always have a not null Preference. I know I can do this in application layer, but (if possible) db layer! Is there a way I could achieve this without making the User the owning side and Preference the inverse side.